# The algebraic structure of $\mathbb{R}(0^{-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I was playing around with adjoining a multiplicative inverse for $0$ to the field $\Bbb R$ and trying to identify what sort of algebraic structure results from that. My initial hypothesis was that it would be an inverse, cancellative monoid, but upon closer inspection, I think that I lose associativity as a result. This is evidenced by the asymmetry,

$$
\begin{align*}
a\cdot0\cdot0^{-1}= &\;(a\cdot0)\cdot0^{-1}=0\cdot0^{-1}=1 \\
&\;a\cdot (0\cdot0^{-1})=a\cdot1=a
\end{align*}
$$
If it's true that I don't even keep associativity after adjoining $0^{-1}$ to $\Bbb R$, what kind of algebraic structure am I left with? Thansk for any help you can provide!

Comment: This has been studied before, see [wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory)

Comment: If you force associativity, you collapse everything to just $0$, because in addition to getting $a=1$ for every $a$, you also get $0=1$, because $0^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0^{-1}\cdot (0+0) = 0^{-1}\cdot 0 + 0^{-1}\cdot 0$, so $1=2$, hence $0=1$.

Comment: See the mathematical notion of "meadow" (which generalizes "field").  For that, the impossible identity $x\cdot x^{-1}=1$ is replaced by $x\cdot x^{-1}\cdot x = x$ and $(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$.

Comment: See localization for an example of how to deal with zero divisors, but there's not much you can do to $0$ itself without getting into algebraic objects that aren't particularly interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard answer is that adjoining an inverse to zero results in the zero ring.

In particular, let’s assuming that by $\mathbb{R}(0^{-1})$, you’re referring to some specific ring in which $0$ has a multiplicative inverse. Generally, one would be referring to a localisation of $\mathbb{R}$ away from $0$. Then we see that $0 = 0 \cdot 0^{-1} = 1$ in this ring, so the ring must be the zero ring.